# Determine if a string contains duplicate words

Tags: regex

I have the following words in a text field (called Criticality):

```
Confidentiality;Confidentiality
```

I want to be able to determine if this field contains duplicate (or reoccurring words)

```
if Criticality == Confidentiality;Confidentiality then Yes (meaning it has words re-occurring.

if Criticality == Confidentiality;Availability then No (meaning it does not have any word re-occuring).
```

I have tried using regex match with the following syntax:

```
$(RegexMatch(Criticality,  /(\b\w+\b)(\s+\1)+/i))
```

but it does not work. Not sure if someone could guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately, regex is not intended for such text operations. Which tool/language do you use ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Your regexp looks for the duplicate words separated by whitespace. But your string has them separated by `;`, not spaces.

Comment: Which RegEx engine are you using?

Comment: Change `\s+` to `;` and it should work. You don't need `+` after the second group, since one duplicate is enough for the match.

Answer (score 1):

Your words are separated by `;`, but the regexp requires them to be separated by `\s+`, which is whitespace.

If you want to allow any non-word characters to separate them, you can use `\W+`.

You should also put `\b` around the back-reference, so it only matches a whole word.

```
(\b\w+\b)(\W+\b\1\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/YN5RER/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex to determine if your field contains duplicate words

`(?<![^;])(\w+)(?![^;])[\S\s]*(?<![^;])\1(?![^;])`

https://regex101.com/r/iOkI9d/1